# PHP array to set the value by finding in the same array by decresing the value digit by 1

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array. like as below:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [prefix] => 93
            [rate] => 0.172962000
            [destination] => Afghanistan
        )
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [prefix] => 9320
            [rate] => 0
            [destination] => Afghanistan (ON-NET)
        )
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [prefix] => 9350
            [rate] => 0
            [destination] => Afghanistan (ON-NET)
        )
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [prefix] => 935
            [rate] => 0.451478000
            [destination] => Afghanistan (ON-NET)
        )
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [prefix] => 9360
            [rate] => 0
            [destination] => Afghanistan (ON-NET)
        )
    )
);
```

I need to set the value to rate in the array which is having `rate = 0`;

**How to set value:**

- I need to pick the prefix value from the array which is having `rate = 0`;
  And need to decrease prefix digit by 1 (Ex: `prefix[9320]` rate is 0; need to decrease by 1 prefix is 932 now).
- And search this value 932 in the same array. If the value is exist in the array and having rate need to set that rate value to `prefix[9320]`.
- If not again need to decrease prefix digit by 1 same as above now the prefix is 93.
- Again need to search the in the array for 93 prefix rate value. If rate exist need to set this rate to `prefix[9320]`.

**I tried like this:**

```
foreach($resdata as $row) {
    if($row[0]['rate'] == 0) {
        $src = $row[0]['prefix']/10;

        foreach($resdata as $row2) {
            if(($src == $row2[0]['prefix']) && ($row2[0]['rate'] != 0)) {
                $row[0]['rate'] = $row2[0]['rate'];
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

**My final array i want as below**

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [prefix] => 93
            [rate] => 0.172962000
            [destination] => Afghanistan
        )
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [prefix] => 9320
            [rate] => 0.172962000
            [destination] => Afghanistan (ON-NET)
        )
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [prefix] => 9350
            [rate] => 0.451478000
            [destination] => Afghanistan (ON-NET)
        )
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [prefix] => 935
            [rate] => 0.451478000
            [destination] => Afghanistan (ON-NET)
        )
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [prefix] => 9360
            [rate] => 0.172962000
            [destination] => Afghanistan (ON-NET)
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried, SO isn't a free coding service

Comment: Just convert your "How to set value" into actual code. You can use recursion for "Cut, search, see rate" actions.

Comment: i have a list of country mobile code prefix list with price charge list.

Comment: I am trying to fix those rate for that country. ex: if the country prefix 9320 not having rate. and 93 is having rate i need to fix that 93 rate to 9320 rate.

Comment: That's something called unreadable question.....

Comment: question updated with code.

Comment: Basheer Ahmed@can you tell me why it is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a `while` loop when decreasing your prefix digit by 1, and then loop the `$resdata` array to see if there is a matching "prefix" to get the "rate".

```
$resdata = array(
    array(array("prefix" => 93, "rate" => "0.172962000", "destination" => "Afghanistan")),
    array(array("prefix" => 9320, "rate" => "0", "destination" => "Afghanistan (ON-NET)")),
    array(array("prefix" => 9350, "rate" => "0", "destination" => "Afghanistan (ON-NET)")),
    array(array("prefix" => 935, "rate" => "0.451478000", "destination" => "Afghanistan (ON-NET)")),
    array(array("prefix" => 9360, "rate" => "0", "destination" => "Afghanistan (ON-NET)"))
);

function getRate($items, $prefix)
{
    while ($prefix = intval($prefix / 10)) {
        foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
            if ($value[0]["prefix"] === $prefix) {
                return $value[0]["rate"];
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

foreach ($resdata as $key => $row) {
    if ($row[0]['rate'] == 0) {
        $rate = getRate($resdata, $row[0]['prefix']);
        if ($rate) {
            $resdata[$key][0]['rate'] = $rate;
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/NHQIB)